# Как быть с точным временем в PHP для разных временных зон?

Tags: php

Проблема в том, что отправляя сообщение из России, час показывает правильно. При отправке из другой страны - Азербайджан - уже на 1 час отстает. И с другими странами тоже проблема.
Как быть, есть ли что-то готовое?

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP по UTC + хранение временной зоны пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Есть классная библиотека для работы с датами и часовыми поясами [Dater](https://github.com/barbushin/dater). О нём есть ещё хорошая статья на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/173693/).